# C++ utility::conversions is not working in Static Linked Library

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, static-libraries, lib

I have a c++ MFC application.
Everything was working for me until I excluded some of the headers i used and set them inside a separated static linked library project.
Now, everything compiles fine, But in runtime, when i try to use utility::conversions library of cpprest sdk, i get an error "UTF-8 string character can never start with 10xxxxxx", for each function in this library i get a different error, and everything becomes "unable to read memory".
But when i use std::to_string() it works just fine (located in different library - not cpprest).
What am i doing wrong?

The pch.h file is located in the library while the MFC app includes it in pch.cpp and configure the precompiled header as 'Create'.

```
// Method in the static library triggered by the MFC app
std::string TradeRecord::toJson(std::string channel)
{
    string_t _channel= utility::conversions::to_string_t(channel);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: No i dont have static variables.

Comment: This is probably something with configuration but i dont know what exactly.

Comment: What exactly does *"static linked library"* mean? Is this a DLL linked at compile-time using an import library, or a static library?

Comment: Static linked library is a "C++ Static Library" project where it's linked to the MFC project by the Linker using (Include additional dependency: .lib file)

Comment: The pch.h file is located in the library while the MFC app includes it in pch.cpp and configure the precompiled header as 'Create'.

Comment: Could be caused by using a mixture of runtime libraries? The runtime library setting needs to be the same for all parts of the application (in general, if you're careful you can mix runtime versions)

Comment: Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) for both.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was working with the release dll version of cpprest library linked to my project, once i linked the debug dll version everything worked perfectly.
So there may be a problem with the library versions.